# How to rotate a sprite on circle in android using Libgdx

Tags: android, textures, libgdx

Dear Fellow Game Developers 
i am newbie to Android Game Development,i like to know how we can develop a sprite rotate in circle on android,with help of libgdx, 
i do have a image in assets folder,cant load it in emulator,following code is using to load image in texture

> texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("1325603701_wordpress.png"));

Comment: Are you having issues to load the texture or rotate the sprite?

Comment: in both...i dont get image or rotate sprite

Comment: Did you check for the answer and did you find the solution?

Answer (score 4):

Create your sprite as following

```
Texture glowBlock = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/glow-block.png"));
Sprite  glowSprite = new com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite(glowBlock);
```

Then in your render method do this

```
@Override
public void render () {
    Gdx.graphics.getGL10().glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    spriteBatch.begin();
    spriteBatch.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    glowSprite.rotate((float) 45.0);
    glowSprite.draw(spriteBatch, 100);
    spriteBatch.end();
}
```

That should give you sprite rotated for 45 degrees

Comment: Is it working for you?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simple way how can you rotate a sprite in libGDX. First you need to set the origin:

```
sprite.setOrigin(sprite.getWidth/2,sprite.getHeight/2);
```

Then you can rotate clockwise and anticlockwise according to your need:

```
sprite.rotate(2f); or sprite.rotate(-2f);
```

Answer (score 1):

If by rotating in a circle you mean WALKING on top of the circumference of a circle, then I guess any of the answers correctly answered your question. So here is my add:

You can continue loading you texture with

```
texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("1325603701_wordpress.png"));
```

but it is extremely recommended that you use the [AssetManager](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Managing-your-assets). About it not loading in the emulator, check if your texture size is power of two. (Like 64x64)

Then create your sprite:

```
sprite = new Sprite(texture);
```

you'll possibly want to pass more arguments to cut the sprite, in case you're using a power of two texture for a non power of two sprite.

Create a helper variable on the class body, to keep track of the time, and one to say where will be the sprite center:

```
private float elapsedTime = 0.0f;
private Vector2 center = new Vector2(10, 10);
```

on render:

```
public void render () {
    final float speed = 30.0f; // in degrees per second
    final float radius = 10.0f; // the radius of the circle you'll be rotating
    float angle = elapsedTime * speed;
    Gdx.graphics.getGL10().glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    spriteBatch.begin();
    sprite.setRotation(angle - 90);
    sprite.setPosition(center.x + radius * (float)Math.cos(angle * MathUtils.degrad), center.y + radius * (float)Math.sin(angle * MathUtils.degrad));
    sprite.draw(spriteBatch);
    spriteBatch.end();
}
```

This should work just fine.

Answer (score -1):

Do it like this 
1. Load your image into AssestLoader class and store it in sprite

```
sprite=new Sprite(AssestLoader.1325603701_wordpress);
```

2.Then set its size , position and color like this

```
sprite.setColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
sprite.setSize(sprite.getWidth(),sprite.getHeight());
sprite.setPosition((w / 2) - (sprite.getWidth() / 2), (h / 2)
                - (sprite.getHeight() / 2));
```

3- In your render method use the below code

```
batch.begin();
sprite.draw(batch);
batch.end();
```

4.Call the rotate method where u want to rotate

```
batch.begin();
this.rotate(deltatime); 
deltatime=deltatime+0.5f;       
batch.end();
```

and

```
public void rotate(float angle)
{
    sprite.setRotation(angle);

}
```

where deltatime is float value=1

Hope this Helps You.

Comment: This is so bad it's hard to know where to start.  Firstly asset manager is off topic to the questiin. Even then your code example is almost senseless. What is this AssestLoader? Then you set the sprite size using its current size.: nonsensical. You then,  for some reason hard code an increase in delta time...  Which makes no sense -  in libgdx talk delta time is the time between frames.  Finally you  create a redundant rotate function which accesses a global.  Horrible. .

Comment: I will just edit the answer in while, sorry for inconvinience @RichieHH